# how to change android buttons space width

Tags: android, android-layout, android-button

I am using android studio for a simple app. I need to have 2 buttons with 50% space each of them. I have this

```
<RelativeLayout

     <Button
            android:layout_weight=".50"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="120px"
            android:text="Lista"
            android:id="@+id/button2"
            android:background="@drawable/blue_btn"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/button" />

        <Button
            android:layout_weight=".50"
            android:layout_width="0px"
            android:layout_height="120px"
            android:text="Penalizo"
            android:background="@drawable/red_btn"
            android:id="@+id/button"

            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/intent3" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

The problem is that buttons aren't displayed 50% blue button takes less space then red button.

Comment: **weights** only work in `LinearLayout` and its derivates!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `LinearLayour`, not `RelativeLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <Button
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <Button
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```